# Show error alert when the data was exist

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, unique

Can anybody help me to create the code for ..
I'm really a beginner for code.

This is the registration form. When I select `noinduk` then I select `level` it shows the error alert if the `level` of `noinduk` primary is exist. Like a unique `level` but it is based on 'noinduk'.

Thank you for help

This is my view

```
<select id="nis" name="nis" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-title="NIS" value="<?php echo set_value("nis"); ?>">
  <option value="none" selected="" disabled="">-- NIS --</option>
  <?php
    if ($nisnya) {
      foreach($nisnya as $row) {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row->kode; ?>"><?php echo $row->kode; ?></option>
  <?php
      }
    }
  ?>
</select>

<div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-2">
  <label for="projectinput3">Paket <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <select id="issueinput5" name="level" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-title="Level" value="<?php echo set_value("level"); ?>">
    <option value="0" selected="" disabled="">-- Paket --</option>
    <?php
      if ($paketnya) {
        foreach($paketnya as $row) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row->kode; ?>"><?php echo $row->nama; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUMli.png)

Comment: Your code is kind of hard to read like this. Can you work on reformatting it?

Comment: i've edited it. please check @frosty